# Yet another infinite type error

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a function that composes a function f with a function g that takes multiple arguments.

```
c :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
c x y z = x(y(z))
lift = c c
```

`(lift $ lift $ lift ... c)` creates the desired function:

```
*Main> (lift $ lift $ lift $ lift $ lift $ c) (\x -> x+2) (\x y z a b c -> x*y*z-(a*b*c)) 1 2 3 4 5 6
-112
```

However, when I attempt to define a function to produce a function that takes f, g, then n arguments (to save typing), the following error occurs:

```
cn 1 = c
cn k = lift (cn(k-1))
<interactive>:9:1: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ c0 -> a
      Expected type: t -> (a -> b) -> a -> b
        Actual type: t -> (a -> b) -> (c0 -> a) -> c0 -> b
    * Relevant bindings include
        cn :: t -> (a -> b) -> a -> b (bound at <interactive>:9:1)
```

Why does this error occur, and how might I resolve it?

Comment: You can't define functions which take an arbitrary number in arguments in Haskell without using typeclass tricks. You're trying to make a function that takes a variable number of arguments, and GHC can't infer a proper type

Comment: Have you tried writing down the type you think `cn` should have?

Comment: Note that "a function g that takes multiple arguments" is actually, for Haskell, a function which takes exactly one argument (and returns another function). There is no way to distinguish between a function with two arguments, and a function with one argument which returns a function. For this reason it's hard to define a general composition function as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make polyvariadic functions in Haskell without typeclasses.

When you try to make a function that takes either one or two arguments, you try to make a function of type `a -> b` and `a -> p -> b`. Hence, the compiler must infer that the type `b` is equivalent to `p -> b`, so the type of the function becomes `a -> p -> p -> p -> ...`. In other words, an infinite type.

A similar problem occurs when you try to make this function. The first line is fine:

```
cn 1 = c
```

This would imply something like `cn :: Int -> (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. However, we now have a problem in the second line:

```
cn k = lift (cn (k-1))
```

Since we know that `cn :: Int -> (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, we must infer that `cn (k-1) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. However, since `lift :: (x -> y -> z) -> x -> (w -> y) -> w -> z`, we see that the return value must be of type `(b -> c) -> (w -> a -> b) -> w -> c`, which clashes with the original type declaration.

TL;DR: you can't change the type of a Haskell function/value via values. This means you can't write polyvariadic functions without certain tricks.